# How to make my tooltip popup where my mouse is in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I created two bar charts using d3 in the same body. My next goal is to create a tooltip to popup whenever my mouse hovers over a bar in one fo the bar graph. The tooltip is going to return the value of y axis for that specific bar. This is what I have so far:

```
// tooltip
const tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
 .attr('class', 'tooltip')
 .style('opacity', 0);


d3.selectAll(".yearBar")
.on("mouseover", function(event, d)
{
    // FIXME your code here
    d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "red")

    const text = d3.select('.tooltip');
    text.text(`Revenue was ${d.Revenue} in ${d.Year}`);
    const [x, y] = d3.pointer(event);

    tooltip
      .attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`)
      .style('opacity', 1);

    console.log("mouse over a year bar")
})
.on("mouseout",function()
{
    // FIXME your code here
    d3.selectAll(".yearBar")
      .style("fill", "#7472c0");
    
    //remove tooltip 
    tooltip.style('opacity', 0);
      
    console.log("mouse leaving a year bar")
});
```

I am using this tooltip as a global variable, so the tooltip should pop up and function for both bar charts. Here is the output [image]

When I hover over a bar the bar turns red and I want the tooltip to come up right above the bar. However, my tooltip is coming up beneath the the bar graph, which is not what I want. I want this to also work for my other bar graph which is beneath the one I presented, when I hover over a bar in that graph the output is and the tooltip appears at the same spot it does for the first bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse enter a bar, `d3.pointer(event)` returns the position of the mouse relative to the bar, which is not where you want to position your tooltip. The tooltip should be positioned based on the data of the bar.
Moreover, it is better to use an element inside the svg to be able to apply a transformation in the same system coordinate as the chart.

Look at this example: https://codepen.io/ccasenove/pen/RwymRdg

The tooltip is a `text` element inside the svg, and the tooltip coordinates are computed using the same scales as the bar in the chart.